# Developing for iPad 1 on Xcode 5/Mavericks

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

From what I can find out, the IOS 5.1 simulator isn't available on Xcode 5/Mavericks.  Am I wrong about that?

The issue is that I'm developing an iPad application, and I want it to run on an iPad 1.  I'd love to target IOS 7 and be done with it, but unfortunately the iPad 1 doesn't support anything past IOS 5.1.  Is there some way to target IOS 5.1 yet be able to debug/test on Xcode 5/Mavericks?

Surely most apps still support the iPad 1 - there are still a lot of iPad 1's out there.  But since the simulator isn't available, it's like Apple isn't letting me upgrade to the latest Xcode and OSX.  What do others do?  I'm hoping there's some way to do this that is eluding me!

Comment: I think a lot of people have just dropped support for iOS 5 or only quasi-support it. I personally wouldn't officially support the iPad 1 even if I did still mostly support iOS 5 because it's so incredibly underpowered. If you need/want to support it, you can still target iOS 5 in Xcode 5, but you should absolutely have an iPad 1 to actually test on, the simulator would never due because of the device's drawing/CPU and especially memory limitations.

Comment: If you really feel the need to develop for the iPad 1 (and iOS 5), buy a used iPad 1 and test on the real device.

Comment: If iPad 1 development is really important to you, you can certainly continue running Xcode 4.5.

Comment: @matt Actually, he cannot. Starting today, February 1st 2014, Apple requires apps uploaded to the AppStore be compiled against the iOS7 SDK and above.

Comment: *there are still a lot of iPad 1's out there:* Here are [some stats](http://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/) on that. Using those numbers, iPad 1 represents 7.9% of iPad usage and 2.4% of all iOS device usage. Those numbers will just keep dropping.

Comment: @LeoNatan You misunderstand the meaning of that rule. He can compile against iOS 7 *and* against iOS 5. (And iOS 6, of course.) Apple will accept that just fine. And if he wants to *work* on the iOS 5 side, he can easily use Xcode 4.5 to do so. Both Xcode 4.5 and Xcode 5.1 can open the same project, if you're careful about it. (Now, don't get me wrong; I think that to develop for iPad 1 in this day and age is pointless. But it can be done.)

Comment: @matt And suppose he calls iOS7 API, conditionally. On Xcode 4.5, with its older SDK version, the project wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @LeoNatan Sure it would. `#if` preprocessor directive prevents code from being seen by the compiler at all. - Look, I didn't say it would be easy! On the contrary, Apple makes backwards compatibility hard. On purpose. It works on me! I *never* try to write backwards compatible code for iOS. It just isn't worth the headache to me. But if he wants to, he wants to.

Comment: I think the nature of the comments has proved that all you're going to get is opinion. Vote to close on that grounds.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the IOS 5.1 simulator isn't available on Xcode 5/Mavericks. However, you can still connect Xcode to a real iPad 1 and develop that way. I bought a used iPad 1 for about $100 specifically for this purpose and it's working fine.

Comment: BTW I originally built most of my apps with iOS 3, so maintaining iOS 5 compatibility is relatively easy. When starting a new app, it's more tempting to embrace the latest API capabilities.